# Importing two different datasets in Veusz

Tags: linux, import, graphics, latex, veusz

I am new in veusz and I cannot figure out how to import two separate datasets as *.dat files into veusz such that I can ultimately create a single data plot with various datasets.

When I import a dataset through  Data--> Import--> Standard -->filename_B.dat,
it just rewrites the previously imported dataset instead of creating a new one...

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can either:

- Enter different dataset names for the columns (space separated) in the "Dataset names" edit box for each file - see the manual on descriptors.
- Or enter different prefix or suffix values (see import dialog) when importing. The prefix and suffix are prepended/appended to the imported name.